# Idiomatic use case for set! in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What are the idiomatic use-cases for `set!` in Clojure?

It's not easy to find uses! I grepped in some of the more popular Clojure OSS projects and there's almost none. The only uses I could find are for setting globals like *warn-on-reflection*, though it's unclear why these are not just set locally with `binding`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question. When you type:

```
(def           foo 42)
(def ^:dynamic bar 43)
```

you are creating a global variable.  In most programming languages, we try to minimize the use global variables as they introduce more complexity and more difficulty in understanding the code (this leads to more errors!).  When we do need global variables, we try to minimize the mutation of those global variables.  This is why you rarely see `set!`, `var-set`, `var-get`, and `alter-var-root` used in Clojure code.

When Clojure code does need to mutate global state, `binding` is often preferred as the `var` in question returns to its previous state when the current thread leaves the scope of the `binding` form. Another benefit is that other threads remain unaffected by any `binding` mutations made by the current thread.

There are several ways to manipulate global variables in Clojure. The answer changes a bit for a *normal* `var` compared to a *dynamic* `var`.  Here are some examples:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core
        tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def            fred      0)
(def ^:dynamic *barney*   0) ; normally use "earmuffs" for dynamic vars
(def ^:dynamic  wilma     0) ; you aren't forced to use use them (but you should!)
(def            betty    29)

(dotest
  (throws?
    (binding [fred 1] ; can't bind non-dynamic var
      (is= fred 1)
      (throws? (set! fred 2))
      (is= fred 2)))

  (is= fred 0)
  (throws? (set! fred 2)) ;  can't set it
  (is= fred 0)
  (throws? (var-set #'fred 3)) ; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change/establish root binding of: fred with set
  (is= fred 0)
  (is= (var-get #'fred) 0)

  (binding [*barney* 3]
    (is= *barney* 3)
    (set! *barney* 4) ; works fine
    (is= *barney* 4))
  (is= *barney* 3)  ; original value once leave binding scope

  (binding [wilma 6]
    (is= wilma 6)
    (set! wilma 7)  ; this works
    (is= wilma 7)
    (alter-var-root #'wilma inc)  ; this doesn't work!
    (is= wilma 7))
  (is= wilma 1)     ; the `inc` altered the root value, not the dynamic value in the `binding`
  (alter-var-root #'wilma #(+ 23 %)) ; can alter root value outside of binding
  (is= wilma 24)

  (is= betty 29)
  (alter-var-root #'betty inc) ; non-dynamic vars can have root value altered
  (is= betty 30)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

`set!` can be used, in combination with thread-local `binding`, to allow functions to communicate *across* the call stack. It is often a convenient way to share state across mutually-recursive functions.

The Clojure compiler is a good example — even though it is implemented in Java — of using of [dynamic Vars](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c0326d2386dd1227f35f46f1c75a8f87e2e93076/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L193) to keep track of internal state.